# How do you preserve emotions in a poem?

Tags: technique, emotions, poetry

I am just another person who writes poems to vent out emotions. I discovered that the amount of emotions that I feel my poem has **during the time of writing**, slowly evaporates away. When I re-read it after some days, the poem just reduces to a dry and incoherent collection of sentences.

Have any other emotional poets in this community felt the same?
If yes, how do you deal with this volatility of emotions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, the pain of all artists. Whatever depiction of reality we create, it's a pale shadow of it. You'll never "get there", nobody does. But you can chase the perfection and approach it.

You need two-pronged approach.

The first prong is that you must think of your audience and relate them to you. You have your emotions unique to you, and whatever caused them nagging you now and here. But it might be a thing that others don't really care about. Good similes, good metaphors that extend it into a relatable territory, into something that will nag everyone else just the same will help a lot. Building a good explanation of just why, just how this impacts you so hard, not just describing your feelings but digging deeper, to justify them, to make people understand and feel the same - not merely reporting your experience, but getting to the heart of it, sharing it - infecting others with it.

The second prong: git gud. You can't train talent or inspiration, but you can train the workshop side, the *craft* side of what is both an art and a craft, till you sweat. Clumsiness, accidental lack of clarity, language errors, bad similes, awkward style, loss of focus, all that can completely ruin your work, and all that is perfectly avoidable by training, learning, paying attention (and learning to pay attention), knowing your tools and when to use them, observing on examples of others what works and what doesn't - that means reading both good and bad poetry! - and not just 'savoring it', but also dissecting, analyzing, what and why worked, how was the goal achieved, what tool made it great, or what broke it?

Talent is not a mystical ability to write great things. Talent is the ability to *learn* fast, efficiently, memorize and utilize the learned knowledge to achieve your goals, have the patience to train where others gave up, recognize and fix your mistakes where others are blinded by their bias. And nothing can replace the inspiration to write something great, but bad workshop can ruin everything, regardless of your inspiration.

Answer (score 2):

when writing, write aloud - I mean taste the words - your ears help you taste them. When you feel finished, read out aloud the whole poem. Try to recite it - convey the feelings till fresh.
You will feel then at once if smth is false or empty or flat - you can correct it - and go on with this writing rewriting procees until exausted.
Returning days after you will have the earlier experience - and can test if it lasts or not.